# How to add more space in `__str__` method of Django model?

Tags: python, django

I want to add more spaces to `__str__` method, but method cut off spaces to 1.

For example:

```
class Spam(models.Model):
    foo = models.IntegerField()
    bar = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return 'more spaces {}            {}!'.format(self.foo, self.bar)
```

This output in Django admin:
`more spaces 1 2`

I want : `more spaces 1            2`

How do this?

Comment: The spaces are there, but web browsers just show any whitespace in HTML as a single space.

Comment: The spaces are most likely not rendered by your browser. That's how the HTML standard defines it.

Answer (score 2):

Where ever your **str** resides:

```
from django.utils import safestring

def __str__(self):
    string = safestring.mark_safe("more spaces {}"+"&nbsp;"*10+ "{}!".format(self.foo, self.bar))
    return string
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the print method it prints ok.

I guess you have a problem with html? Replace whitespaces with `&nbsp;` (but then it looks like crap in the shell) or try a more explicit representation in admin...

Or you could try wrapping the string in the `<pre>` tag

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with django, but you are checking the results at web-page, indeed.

So full answer for your question will be:
You should use special HTML symbols for HTML-page to indent your second part of text. You can check special symbols here: http://www.wikihow.com/Insert-Spaces-in-HTML

To use '&nbsp' you can do:

```
def __str__(self):
    space_sym = "&nbsp"*10 # hardcode magic-number of indent spaces
    return 'more spaces {}{}{}!'.format(self.foo, space_sym, self.bar)
```

Comment: This is a partial answer: Django escapes by default, so you will need to add the `|safe` template tag in the template for these spaces not to be escaped